# Should i make a rpm or deb package or use the Qt Installer Framework

Tags: qt, deployment, installation, cross-platform, rpmbuild

I want to deploy my app cross platform for linux i am confused,
Should i build separate packages for Redhat and Debian or use an installer script like Qt Installer Framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your exact desire, but ideally, you could do both.

Rpms, debs, and similar packages for other distributions are easier to obtain and install.

However, sometimes it takes the distrubtion a while to get your software into their package repositories. In those cases, having an installer like Qt does comes handy.